# Ionic2 cloud google login with asp.net web api

Tags: asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, ionic2

I am building an ionic2 app and implemented google login flow. Which works fine and i get the token after a success full. How do i use this token to authenticate my project web api Endpoint  ( using Oauth for generating the tokens). I am using default asp.net web api project template

Comment: Did you figure this out?